# how can i animate my wpf control to right to left

Tags: wpf

I want to move my lable control from right to left in my wpf application.
How can i do this using wpf animation or is there any other way to do this.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

I recommand you to [check this post](http://pradeepmahdevu.blogspot.com/2009/02/flying-grids-using-margin-animation.html). It animate two grids, but it's quite the same process to animate your label.

Comment: thnaks for your help ..but i am looking  for some marquee type animation.